# Extjs, How to ignore maxHeight when maximize the window?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Extjs 4.2, How i can ignore `maxHeight` config when window maximized?
I want to make fullscreen window.

This's my demo code in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zbyHY/

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        title: 'Hello',
        maximizable: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        maxHeight: 350
    }).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ready for a major hack?

```
function realMaximize(){
    if(this.maxInternal){
        return;
    }
    if(this.maximized){
        this.oldMaxHeight = this.maxHeight;
        this.maxHeight = undefined;
        this.maxInternal = true;
        this.restore();
        this.maximize();
        this.maxInternal = false;
    }else{
        this.maxHeight = this.oldMaxHeight;
    }
}

Ext.onReady(function() {
    var w = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        title: 'Hello',
        maximizable: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        maxHeight: 350
    });
    w.addListener('maximize',realMaximize);
    w.show();
});
```

ugh! Horrible. What does it do? When it detects a maximize, it stores the current maximum height and removes it. Then it toggles the maximisation so that the UI updates to respect this new maximum (maybe there is a better way?). Finally, it has to set and check a flag or it would get in an infinite loop (`maximize` calls the function again).

Going back to windowed isn't so hard; the remembered size must be OK, so we don't need to call the function recursively.

Comment: If anyone knows how to simulate the window resizing, or trigger a size update in some other way, this could be made much cleaner.

Comment: Do yo think i should report this issue (maxHeight/maximize) to Sencha? or Is this a (good) feature (maxHeight break maximize)?

Comment: I'd report it. It's not behaviour which I would expect as the user.

Comment: It's not a bug, technically. Rather, the behavior is programmed into setSize() of AbstractComponent: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/AbstractComponent.html#Ext-AbstractComponent-method-setSize

I agree, however, that it is unexpected behavior. It would be nice, at the very least, to have some easier override method provided for this very scenario.

Comment: I agree this is not a bug but it seem to be feature conflict. Do yo have idea to override some method to give the choice in this scenario.